# How to Javascript to replace HTML text with new text when the HTML may have children elements

Tags: javascript, html, regexp-replace

I am trying to use JavaScript to search through all of the p elements to find a regular expressions, but the text that I am looking for may or may not partially exist in an attribute element or contained within a span.  Ultimately, I plan to fix the cross references in the HTML code that were applied in Word to a Word bullet item by adding an attribute element with a reference to an html id that I have previously inserted with JavaScript.

My overall project is to create a Word document that I use the Save As function to have Word create a filtered HTML file.  I am ultimately using JavaScript to insert ids and tags so that I can utilize a CSS file to standardize formatting of all my HTML files.  Due to this, I have limited control of the initial HTML code.

Thus far I have been able to create a loop through all of the p elements.  Within the loop, I am able to do a conditional statement for the regular expression on the innerText for "/Step (\d+)/" since I expect that the text will look something like Step 1, Step 12, or any other number. The code below seems to successfully enter if statement.  I am running into trouble with the replace function for the innerHTML portion because the innerText matches the expression, but the innerHTML contains the  element that prevents the final results that I am looking for.  I would like to be able to generically account for any other element such as bold, italics, a, etc.  To account for this, I have tried to use multiple if statements to replace various potential HTML conditions.

I am trying to figure out this skill by just being able to apply bold to the text to ensure that I understand how to complete this particular function.  So far all of the searches that I have done have helped get the regular expression to match the innerText, but I can't find a method or ignoring the extraneous html code.  I was thinking that it might be possible to store replaced innerText with the new HTML code and then make that the new innerHTML, but there could be other formatting in the p element that I want to maintain.

With the approach that I am taking to use a second regular expression for the innerHTML replace, the greedy search it seems like I would catch false results even if the regular expression was catching it.

HTML

```
<p id="FirstPara" class=firstpara>This is a header</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206; </span><b>1</b>.</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206;</span>2.</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206;</span>1 and Step <span lang=HE>&#8206;</span>2.</p>
```

JavaScript function

```
function findTheText() {
    regExp1 = /Step (\d)/g;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('p').length; i++) {
                alert(i+" - "+j+" - "+document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i].innerHTML+" - "+results[j]);
        var results = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i].innerText.match(regExp1);
        if (results !== null) {
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                var replace = results[j].replace(/Step\s/,"");
                var regExp2 = new RegExp('Step\s'+replace,"i");
                var regExp3 = new RegExp('Step\s.*>'+replace,"i");
                var regExp4 = new RegExp('Step\s.*>.*>'+replace,"i");
                var results2 = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i].innerText.match(regExp2);
                var results3 = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i].innerText.match(regExp3);
                var results4 = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i].innerText.match(regExp4);
                    if (results2 !== null) {
                        document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i].innerHTML.replace(regExp2, "<b>"+results[j]+"</b>");
                    } else if (results3 !== null) {
                        document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i].innerHTML.replace(regExp3, "<b>"+results[j]+"</b>");
                    } else if (results4 !== null) {
                        document.getElementsByTagName('p')[i].innerHTML.replace(regExp4, "<b>"+results[j]+"</b>");
                    }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As of now the code will find the text that I want, but since the regular expression matches the strings that I am looking for, but the innerHTML does not I am not achieving the bold (or eventually attributes) on the text.

Expected HTML output

```
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to <b>Step 1</b>.</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to <b>Step 2</b>.</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to <b>Step 1</b> and <b>Step 2</b>.</p>
```

Comment: The problem I'm running into is that the `span` between `Step` and the number contains a character, so the very initial `/Step (\d)/` pattern fails: https://jsfiddle.net/j8yxwa2p/ Maybe first remove all `<span lang=HE>` tags?

Comment: One option I was thinking about was running the html code through a VBA script to try and clear out that text, but I think I am going to run into the same issues because these were only a sample of what might be in the original html code.

I will have some control to these extra HTML items because I plan to use some standardization when creating the Word document but I expect there might be other cases.  I added an example to the question where just the number is bold in addition to the span where the entire Step # should be bold as well.  That was my hope with the "if" regular expressions.

Comment: Can there be any nested tags inside the span? If not, it wouldn't be that hard to match `Step`s around them and replace as desired

Comment: I do not believe that I should ever see additional nested tags inside the span.  I believe Word generated those because I created a cross-reference in the Word document prior to generating the HTML.  I know those cross-reference have to be added prior generating for my situation.

The only other tag I really anticipate is bolding as I have added to the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might remove all child `span`s and then check the `textContent` to ignore the rest of the markup (like `<b>`s), capturing the step digit and replacing with that surrounded by `<b>` and `</b>`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((p) => {
  p.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(span => span.remove());
  p.innerHTML = p.textContent.replace(/Step +(\d+)/g, '<b>Step $1</b>');
});
```

```html
<p id="FirstPara" class=firstpara>This is a header</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206; </span><b>1</b>.</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206;</span>2.</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206;</span>1 and Step <span lang=HE>&#8206;</span>2.</p>
```

To only remove `span`s with a `lang` of `HE`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((p) => {
  p.querySelectorAll('span[lang="HE"]').forEach(span => span.remove());
  p.innerHTML = p.textContent.replace(/Step +(\d+)/g, '<b>Step $1</b>');
});
```

```html
<p class=firstpara>This is a <span>reference</span> to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206; </span><b>1</b>.</p>
```

Comment: This definitely achieves the goal for that snippet of HTML.  I was trying out the code and noticed that all span elements are taken out, so I tried some conditional statements to only consider innerText paragraphs with step numbers.  The situation that I was not able to get around was if the paragraph was: <p class=firstpara>This is a <span>reference</span> to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206; </span><b>1</b>.</p> in which case the text was removed.  Do you know any way around this?  I keep unsuccessfully going back to trying multiple regular expressions as in my original code.

Comment: If you can count on the bad spans that you want to remove always having `lang` attributes of `HE`, remove those specifically, and nothing else, see edit

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure this is the result you expect, but this code may work. You can even update it to use arrow functions and template literals.

```js
function findTheText() {
  let regExp1 = /Step (\d)/g;
  let paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

  for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    let spans = Array.from(paragraphs[i].getElementsByTagName('span'));
    spans.forEach(function(child) {
      paragraphs[i].removeChild(child);
    })

    if (paragraphs[i].innerHTML.match(regExp1)) {
      let replace = paragraphs[i].innerHTML.match(regExp1);
      replace.forEach(function(match) {
        paragraphs[i].innerHTML = paragraphs[i].innerHTML.replace(match, "<b>" + match + "</b>");
      })
    };
  }
}

findTheText()
```

```html
<p id="FirstPara" class=firstpara>This is a header</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206; </span>1.</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206;</span>2.</p>
<p class=firstpara>This is a reference to Step <span lang=HE>&#8206;</span>1 and Step <span lang=HE>&#8206;</span>2.</p>
```

Comment: Note that the `1` may be inside a tag as well. `</span><b>1</b>.</p>`

Comment: You're right, thanks for the heads up. Also when I saw the solution you proposed I realised the mine is needlessly long. Thank you  :)